# Use of a function as parameter of a function: why use of anonym function?

Tags: javascript, function

I created a function which is called when an event happens. The direct call of my function doesn't work and I need to use an anonymous function. Why do I need to do so? Could someone explain the logic to avoid me to loose time for such stupid mistakes?

Doesn't work because direct call to the function checkInBackEnd

```
$('#signup-email').change(
    checkInBackEnd($('#signup-email'), 'email-unique.php', function(result){
        if(result == 1){
            $('#signup-error-email').show();
        }
        else{
            $('#signup-error-email').hide();
        }
    })
);
```

It works because I use an anonymous function is the change function:

```
$('#signup-email').change(function(){
    checkInBackEnd($('#signup-email'), 'email-unique.php', function(result){
        if(result == 1){
            $('#signup-error-email').show();
        }
        else{
            $('#signup-error-email').hide();
        }
    });
);
```

Thank you

Comment: That happens because `checkInBackEnd($(...))` is a function call. You should not call a function when _a reference is expected_. Or if you're going to, take care, that the called function returns a function reference (or an anonymous function).

Comment: So as I understand, we cannot call a function directly in the parameters of a function? We need to use a anonymous function all the time?

Comment: We can, but if we should, depends on how that particular parameter is used in the originally invoked function.

Comment: No, you can use a named function, just as long as it doesn't need any parameters, so you could do `.change( myownfunction )`. Note that the function must be declared at the moment the change method is called otherwise you're passing undefined to it.

Comment: OK. Thank you. So what is important is to check what `change` expects as parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't have to be an anonymous function. You can define a named function:

```
function doCheckIn() {
    checkInBackEnd($('#signup-email'), 'email-unique.php', function(result){
    if(result == 1){
        $('#signup-error-email').show();
    }
    else{
        $('#signup-error-email').hide();
    }
}
```

and then pass that as the callback argument:

```
$('#signup-email').change(doCheckIn);
```

We usually use anonymous functions because these callback functions are only needed in that one place. There's no need to give it a name if it will only be used once. After a while you'll get used to this idiom.

But the important thing is that the argument to an event binding function has to be a function. The function shouldn't be called until the event is triggered. If you put a function call in `.change()`, the function will be called at the time you're setting up the event binding, not later.

Answer (score 0):

Break up your code to better understand: First lets look at a simplified example:

```
function fakeChangeFunction(myFn) {
  val result = myFn(); // We expect to have a function
  doSomethingWithResult(result);
}

function myChangeFunctionExample() {
  alert('foobar');
  // returns undefined implicitly
}

// Doesn't work
fakeChangeFunction(myChangeFunctionExample()); // This will cause an error

// Works
fakeChangeFunction(myChangeFunctionExample); // Notice no parenthasis

// Works
fakeChangeFunction(function() {
  myChangeFunctionExample();
});

// Works
function returnsAFunction() {
  return function() {
    alert('barfoo');
  };
}

fakeChangeFunction(returnsAFunction());
```